# Link para download de *.exe

Tags: html

Preciso baixar um arquivo ***.exe** através de link na *tag* href, fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
<a href="remoto.exe"><input type="button" id="botao" title="Suporte HSS" value="Suporte HSS"></a><br><br><br>
```

Porém o download sempre da erro. Se eu altero para baixar uma imagem o link funciona normalmente. É necessário alguma alteração para baixar arquivo ***.exe**?

Comment: `remoto.exe` é um arquivo em outro servidor? ou no mesmo path que está seu html?

Comment: @Renan Esta no mesmo Path

Comment: ok, e qual é o erro?

Answer (score 2):

Se o erro for algo como:

> Interrompido

ou

> Falhou

ou

> falha na rede

**Não tem como resolver** no HTML, usar o atributo `download` do HTML5 não vai fazer funcionar, `.exe` geralmente já baixa diretamente, esse atributo nada tem haver com o problema.

É provável que seja alguma configuração em seu servidor, não tem como analisar, só com uma ferramenta como WireShark ou talvez analisando as configurações do Apache.

Mas é mais provável que seja algo em seu computador, como um antivírus que bloqueia, a extensão `.exe`, uso antivírus no computador da empresa, ele sempre bloqueia os `.exe`.

> eu passei uma situação semelhante, criei um *patch* pros funcionários conseguirem instalar a atualização do software sozinhos, eles baixavam `.exe`, no entanto não funcionou, fui verificar e era o mesmo erro (provavelmente) que o seu

Então para ter certeza tente desativar:

- antivirus
- windowsdefender

E tente fazer o download novamente, provavelmente irá funcionar, no entanto isso não é um bom caminho e nem uma solução, afinal não são todos computadores que você irá poder fazer isso no momento do download.

O ideal seria mudar a extensão para algo como `.zip`, isso fez os download não serem mais interrompidos.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca o atributo `download` na tag `<a>`.

Comment: Já tentei colocar o atributo `download`

Comment: você está tentando em qual navegador?

Comment: Tentei em chrome, mozilla e IE

Comment: Responder, responde sim. O problema é que a pergunta está mal formulada e não explica qual é o "erro". Da forma como a pergunta está atualmente, essa resposta é totalmente válida.

Answer (score 1):

Você deveria adicionar um atributo `download` na sua tag

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  Download
</a>
```

Outra coisa que me chamou atenção é que você esta adicionando link em um input type="button", o que não me parece certo.

Caso não funcione voce pode adicionar um pequeno form para gerar o botão de download

```
<form method="get" action="SEUAQUIVO.exe"> 
  <button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Já tentei colocar o atributo `download`

Comment: A ideia do Botão é que o usuário ao clicar no botão faça o download

Comment: Usa css pra formatar esse botão, e não de fato um input type button

Comment: Um outro caminho é você criar um form para o download. Editei a resposta adicionado essa sugestão